How can I share a temp table between transactions on Postgresql?
How can I share a temp table between transactions on Postgresql?

You can't.  The whole concept of a transaction is that it is atomic and isolated -- nothing is actually visible until the transaction is committed.

"Temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session, or optionally at the end of the current transaction (see ON COMMIT )"   Conclusion: in 1 session you can share records from previous transaction.

If you are looking for something that bridges native Postgres temp tables and the answer from @Zegarek below you might want to take a look at the extensionPostgreSQL Global Temporary Tables.

If you're thinking about a temp table that's available to multiple users, clients, workers, sessions, you're thinking about an unlogged table:
create unlogged table t1(id int);

Performance and reliability wise, it's the same thing but unlike temporary tables, it has global scope and doesn't get wiped or dropped between transactions. Note that similar to temp which just disappears altogether, its contents don't survive a database crash either:

Data written to unlogged tables is not written to the write-ahead log (see Chapter 30), which makes them considerably faster than ordinary tables. However, they are not crash-safe: an unlogged table is automatically truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown. The contents of an unlogged table are also not replicated to standby servers.
Any indexes created on an unlogged table are automatically unlogged as well. If this is specified, any sequences created together with the unlogged table (for identity or serial columns) are also created as unlogged.

If you really mean a temp table that's scoped to a single session's exclusive pg_temp schema but survives between transactions, the on commit clause lets you specify that behaviour, as already pointed out by @Luuk.
Thing is, the default is on commit preserve rows, as opposed to on commit drop, so if you don't override that and just create a temp, then both the table and its contents stay untouched by commit and rollback, until you explicitly wipe it or drop it, or close the session that created the temp table.

The data doesn't survive a crash or restart, the table however does still exist after restarting. It's just empty. However, they are not crash-safe: an unlogged table is automatically truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown. The contents of an unlogged table are also not replicated to standby servers.

@FrankHeikens Thanks, that's a pretty important distinction. I corrected that part.
